# Dragon age Inquisition not responding with controller?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, dragon-age-inquisition

I'm using a PS3 controller plugged into my computer with an emulator to let me play it as a Xbox controller. It's all fine and dandy on other games, but the moment I switch to controller on Dragon Age Inquisition, the game crashes. I open it again and the controller lets me click start, moves me to the home screen, and just doesn't let me do anything. It makes a noise when I move my joystick, but nothing changes. I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>del</kbd> and the screen advances to the character creation screen, but it's glitchy.

Before you ask, no I do not have two different controllers plugged in, no I don't have anything razer on my computer at all, and no I don't have any FPS tracking software or origin overlay on or anything like that. I've tried everything I've found and nothing is working; the funny thing is, my controller worked perfectly before I updated my game. Please help.